# Is it possible to connect to several servers and search for text in a log?

Tags: linux

I have 8 web servers and 8 app servers on each of which I need to find a particular string of text.

Typically I would connect to the server through putty and type this below to search for that text:

```
grep "XMemcached network layout exception" /logs/handle1.log
```

Is there anyway I can automate this via a script, so it will automatically connect to those servers and search for those words?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Log in on one of the servers and do something like

`for host in web1 web2 web3 [...] app1 app2 app3 [...]; do ssh $host grep "XMemcached network layout exception" /logs/handle1.log | sed "s/^/$host: /"; done`

This is just a basic one-off script; if you find yourself doing that kind of things repeatedly, consider installing [`clusterssh`](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/551).

Comment: Thanks a lot , what this will do ?? sed "s/^/$host: /";

Comment: It may be really useful to use SSH-agent forwarding when logging in the initial server.

Comment: hey thank you very much , is is not required to give the username and password for the hosts in the list ??

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I do such tasks over ssh.

Setup a ssh authentication without passwords but with certificates. On your (monitoring) computer, where you start the grep command, you need to generate a ssh key with `ssh-keygen`. This will create a keypair for you in your `~/.ssh/` Folder. A private, secret one an another public one. You need to copy the public key to every target computer you want to search for logs. You can copy the file with `scp` to the target computer. Afterwards log in into the target computer and append the content of the public key file to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Now you should be able to login to the target computer from your monitoring computer without a password.
Please verify this by trying to log on with `ssh <target computer>`.

If this works you can just `cat` the log file over the ssh connection to your local grep command as follows:

```
echo `ssh <user>@<target computer> "cat <log file>"` | grep <search term>
```

That's only one solution, that is very easy and quickly established.
With this solution you always stay on your local monitoring computer and only retrieve the log files you want to search through.
A more comfortable solution would probably to write a little bash script.

Comment: +1 ..and why not just use the grep as command to ssh, instead of `cat`ing all over the network? I think your explanation, along with @DomQ oneliner, make a great answer.

Comment: Ehm, yes that's true. Why doing it the easy way when it can be done more complicated. ;)
Using grep on remote site instead of cat will save a great amount of bandwidth indeed. I initially thought about something like
echo `ssh <user>@<target computer1> "cat <log file>"` <user>@<target computer 2> "cat <log file>"` <user>@<target computer3> "cat <log file>"` | grep <search term>, so that i only need to specify the search term once. But saving bandwidth and faster execution time should be preferred instead.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like RabbitMQ to connect boxes together for things like this.

Then, using http://sphinxsearch.com/ to help on the searching side is helpful.

Personally, I would pipe all of the logs through rabbit to a central search server. If the search traffic is substantial, maybe using a few boxes.